# Delete Folder With Contents In SSH Server

Tags: php, file-io

I'm trying to delete a folder and all the files that in it, in a SSH server.
The thing is that I don't know how ssh2 works. I changed the connection to ssh2, but maybe those function doesn't works in a ssh server, I don't know...

My code:

```
$ftpuser = '***';
$ftppass = '***';
$dir = 'files/someFolder/';
$connection = ssh2_connect('**.***.***.***',22);

if(!$connection) {
    error_log("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
    exit;
}
$login_result = ssh2_auth_password($connection, $ftpuser, $ftppass);

ftp_chdir($connection, $dir);
$folders_files = ftp_nlist($connection, '.');
foreach ($folders_files as $folder_file) {
    ftp_delete($connection, $folder_file);
}
ftp_rmdir($connection, $dir);
```

There are some errors:

```
PHP Warning:  ftp_chdir(): supplied resource is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in...
PHP Warning:  ftp_nlist(): supplied resource is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in...
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...
PHP Warning:  ftp_rmdir(): supplied resource is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in...
```

What the hell is going on here?

Comment: Are you in the correct directory ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I tried to do that with `ftp_chdir` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing the ssh2_* functions and the ftp_* functions. They're not interchangeable.

That said I'd recommend using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/intro.html). An example:

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$sftp->delete('dirname.remote', true); // deletes a directory and all its contents
?>
```

The fact that it can recursively delete stuff should be particularly useful to you. ie. if files/someFolder/ contains a folder A that itself contains another folder, folder B, you probably won't be able to delete it with your method whereas with phpseclib's deletion approach can delete it.

Comment: Put `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3)` at the top and do a <pre> at the top too and post a pastebin link to the output.

Comment: Are you sure `/root/uploads/kRZOCPlPp` actually exists? If it does does the user you're logging into the SFTP server with via phpseclib have permissions to see it? Here's a more thorough explanation: http://pastebin.com/H4V26dL8

Comment: Sorry, you were right. The folder path wasnn't right. I found it using:
`$sftp->sftp_errors[]`. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

**You must be inside a non-existent directory.**

This code will help you understand what you are doing wrong.

```
echo "Current directory: " . ftp_pwd($connection) . "\n";

// try to change the directory to somedir
if (ftp_chdir($connection, "files/someFolder/")) {
    echo "Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($connection) . "\n";
} else { 
    echo "Couldn't change directory\n";
}
```

Comment: It gives another Error: `PHP Warning:  ftp_chdir(): supplied resource is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in...`

Comment: The output is: `Current directory:` and then nothing